# Disable Setting button on android keyboard

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, keyboard, mvvmcross

I want to disable these buttons on my android keyboard tablet :

[image]

Because, if the user press these buttons, they can quit my application, and normally, they can't

I develop with Visual Studio 2015 Xamarin in MVVMCross

How can i do that ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can't disable these buttons as far as I know. And even if you could, a user can always install other keyboards that you don't have control over.

Modifier keys are not triggering the EditorAction event of an EditText control, so those won't help you (only for Done and Del, for example). The OnKeyUp or OnKeyDown event won't help you either.

One solution could be to implement a keyboard like banking apps often do, however that would be a hassle for a complete keyboard (most banking apps only show digits for a PIN-code). It depends on the specific use case and context of your app if this would work  for you.

But really think about why you would want to prevent the user from quitting the app. If it is needed for an enterprise or school, there are solutions with Mobile Device Management that should work. An app for taking exams for example, would require this.